# Advanced datatable row filter for DateTime - specific days of the week

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is it possible to have a more advanced data table filter. so for my case i can filter between date ranges. but what if i only wanted to show mondays / day of week using the filter?

```
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(1,"One", new DateTime(2000,01,01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Two", new DateTime(2001, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Three", new DateTime(2002, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(4, "Four", new DateTime(2003, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(5, "Five", new DateTime(2004, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(6, "Six", new DateTime(2005, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(7, "Seven", new DateTime(2006, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(8, "Eight", new DateTime(2007, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(9, "Nine", new DateTime(2008, 01, 01));


        dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Date >= #2001/01/01# AND Date <= #2008/01/01#";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `RowFilter` to filter by "day of the week". Try to loop through the whole DataTable row by row, or use LINQ.

Here is a LINQ demo.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2001, 01, 01);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2008, 01, 01);

var result = dataTable
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where(myRow => myRow.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= startDate 
                    && myRow.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= endDate 
                    && myRow.Field<DateTime>("Date").DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Test result:

[image]